# Could I use a 'dry' job? if not, alternative?

Tags: word-request

In my native language, we use 'dry' as an adjective for job. I searched "dry job" in Google and Google Scholar and I guess this usage is not common or appropriate in English. Please tell me whether use of 'dry' in this context sounds natural or not. Also I'm very willing to know other adjectives that collate with job with a close meaning. I know the obvious ones like boring but I want it to be more close to dry.

**Update:**
Thanks to @Jeff comment, it really helped when I thought about the meaning of 'dry' in my language context. A 'dry job' means a job that involves almost no flexibility not just in terms of job schedule, but you can't use your imagination or creativity to change things there. It's always the same and usually there is some authoritative belief or force to maintain this state in the job. Some clerk, military, or manual jobs look like this. With this little thought about the meaning I've came to the words 'rigid' or 'inflexible' but I don't think they can be readily used with 'job'. I would like a combination of 'rigid' and 'boring' if there were any word for that. Thank you all for reading my obsessions about words!

Comment: Please describe what the meaning of "dry job" is, in context. It might also help if you would identify your native language; idioms that have the same _literal_ translation in English may not have the same _meaning_.

Comment: I don't think there are any English idioms relating to jobs that draw on the metaphoric associations of ***dry*** in this way. We'd use it like that when talking about *a dry speech* (a boring speech/address/presentation), but not with a job. Consider using a completely different approach, such as [McJob](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mcjob) (but note that's more about the job being "undemanding", with few prospects for advancement, rather than *boring*.

Comment: Wet work is assassin work

Comment: A  somewhat tongue-in-cheek suggestion: Look up [jejune](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jejune), which [this Merriam-Webster article](https://www.merriam-webster.com/news-trend-watch/viral-vocabulary-size-test-sends-people-to-the-dictionary-20160714?src=defrecirc-fromthem-w) describes as one of the most  puzzling candidates in vocabulary tests. While it may be fitting, it's unlikely your audience will actually *understand* it. ;-)

Comment: You may want to consider "monotonous" among the candidate words.  Google's auto-suggestions regarding the phrase "a monotonous job" seem appropriate for your purpose.  It literally means unchanging in musical pitch, but it's a common metaphor for any lack of change (especially when it inspires a lack of interest) and it collocates well with "job", "task" and "work".

Comment: Your guesses of “rigid” and “inflexible” are probably what I would say. I don’t see why they can’t be used with “job”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that "Dry job" is not a used idiom in English. Words that we would use to describe a job that is "rigid" or "inflexible" include:

**Monotonous**

**Strict**

**Unchanging**

**Repetitive** (Similar to boring but related more closely to "dry")

**Constant**

Examples:

> The man's job as a clerk was very **repetitive.**
>
> The woman's **strict** occupation as a military personnel was **unchanging**.(Occupation is another word for job)
>
> Being a dentist is a **monotonous** job.

This is my first time answering a question, so I hope I helped. :)

Comment: Welcome to SE @Ben. Your answer was really of help to me